# Include null characters in C# StringBuilder string

Tags: c#, string, pinvoke, stringbuilder

I'm calling a C library function from a C# method; something like this:

```
[DllImport("libfoo.dll")]
public static extern int GetData(StringBuilder buffer);
```

It returns the number of characters that it put into the buffer, and there's a known maximum limit on the number of characters; so it could be called like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5000);

int received = GetData(sb);
```

So the problem/question: the C function is using a character array as a byte array; we're not necessarily looking at normal strings, and the character array may well include null characters.

It seems that this default, naive usage of StringBuilder results in a C# string that is cut off at the first null character / null byte.

What else could be done? Is there a way to force StringBuilder to accept strings with null characters? Or is there a better approach for accessing the C library function?

Edit: C function is something like:

```
int GetData (char *buffer);
```

Comment: SB doesn't encapsulate a char array, so treating it as one is a flawed premise.

Comment: What is the signature of the C method?

Comment: A C string uses a 0 to indicate the end of the string.  There is no additional Length-like member, it is merely an array of characters.  So, inevitably, zeros can not give you what you want.  The pinvoke marshaller has to stop copying chars when it encounters a 0.  You must include another *out* argument or return value that indicates how many chars were copied into the buffer.  And use byte[] instead.  Use Encoding.Default.GetString(byte[], int, int) to convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so as Fredou pointed out, StringBuilder strings can have null characters, but something was still getting lost in between the C code and the C# code. Turns out that StringBuilder usually is a fine choice for receiving regular strings, but for byte arrays, using, well, a byte array works better.

Answer here: [PInvoke char* in C DLL handled as String in C#. Issue with null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273783/pinvoke-char-in-c-dll-handled-as-string-in-c-issue-with-null-characters)

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to convert the StringBuilder into array of string you can always do

```
var myArray = sb.ToString().Split('\0');
```

[ex(dotnetfiddler);](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6Cfo1)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("abc\0def");

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        var myArray = sb.ToString().Split('\0');

        Console.WriteLine("myArray.Length " + myArray.Length);
        foreach(var a in myArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I will also add that StringBuilder do support null character, example above prove it

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to interpret regular bytes using a string in C#. Why don't you pass a normal byte array instead, if you know its maximum size?

```
[DllImport("libfoo.dll")]
public static extern int GetData([Out] byte[] buffer);
```

Comment: That's right. It's also what the OP already posted as an answer 8 hours ago.