# C++ string to C# using a struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct, dllimport

Is there a way to send a String from C++ to C# by using a struct? I have a struct with image data (data and size), in this struct I would like to have barcode data from the image too. I have tried to do it via a IntPtr in C#, but that return gibberish and via a Stringbuilder, but then the struct cannot be marshalled. See below for all the code in question

C# struct

```
public struct ImageInfo
{
    public IntPtr data; // image data, works
    public int size;    // image data, works

    // string
    //public IntPtr barcodeType; // return gibberish
    //public IntPtr barcodeData; // return gibberish

    public StringBuilder barcodeType; //Cannot marshal field 'barcodeType' of type 'ImageProcessingOpenCv.ImageInfo'
    public StringBuilder barcodeData; //Cannot marshal field 'barcodeData' of type 'ImageProcessingOpenCv.ImageInfo'
}
```

C# import:

```
[DllImport("AlgorithmsCpp.dll", EntryPoint = "ScanBarcode", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void ScanBarcode(byte[] data, int dataLen, ref ImageInfo imTemplate);
```

Call to C++ and how I tried getting string from IntPtr:

```
ImageInfo imInfo = new ImageInfo();
AlgorithmCpp.ScanBarcode(sourceImagePixels, sourceImagePixels.Length, ref imInfo); // wont work with StringBuilder.

string stringa = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(imInfo.barcodeType); // result: gibberish
stringa = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(imInfo.barcodeType);        // result: gibberish
stringa = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(imInfo.barcodeType);        // result: gibberish
stringa = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(imInfo.barcodeType);         // result: gibberish
stringa = Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8(imInfo.barcodeType);        // result: gibberish

// example what is returned: "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\0\0\0"
```

C++ struct:

```
struct ImageInfo
{
    unsigned char* data;
    int size;

    // String
    //unsigned char* barcodeType; // for IntPtr, return gibberish
    //unsigned char* barcodeData; // for IntPtr, return gibberish

    char* barcodeType; // for StringBuilder
    char* barcodeData; // for StringBuilder
};
```

How I have tried to return a string from C++

```
#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DllExport void ScanBarcode(unsigned char* data, int dataLen, ImageInfo& imInfo)
{
    // do stuff to get barcode

    // for IntPtr
    std::string type = symbol->get_type_name();
    std::string data = symbol->get_data();

    imInfo.barcodeType = (unsigned char*)type.c_str();
    imInfo.barcodeData = (unsigned char*)data.c_str();

    // For StringBuilder
    strcpy(imInfo.barcodeData, symbol->get_data().c_str());
    strcpy(imInfo.barcodeType, symbol->get_type_name().c_str());
}
```

I hope with the code above I have given you a understanding what I have tried and what I want to have. If you require any further information let me know and I will try giving it.

Comment: @Fildor reading the internet for possible solutions. I saw StringBuilder multiple times so I tired it out. I have no answer why I should, or shouldn't use it.

Comment: As for `IntPtr` approach, you assign `imInfo.barcodeType/Data` to local variable `type/data` internal pointer, which are deleted on function exit, thus points at gibberish.

Comment: Per [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke) `char *` can be marshalled to either `string` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yep, wasn't aware of of that. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274893/982149 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450756/982149

Comment: @wes Have a look at msdn [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions), try to decorate you `struct` with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`, since you're using an ansi string. Or add `MarshalAs` to string fields

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I assume you mean witj IntPtr, this hase the same result. `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(imInfo.barcodeType);` still return gibberish. Return: `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\0\0\0"`

Comment: why you think that c_str() can be returned outside the method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you tried to read the string from C++, the result will be the same (hopefully; the alternative is far worse :)). The pointer you're storing in the structure is only valid within the method `ScanBarcode`. C++ doesn't have automatic memory management - you need to be very careful about who allocates memory and how it's supposed to be freed!

Comment: What do you mean @Selvin? I store the information in a struct and I return that. the `c_str()` is needed in this case as `type` (in c++) is a std::string

Comment: @Selvin You're entirely right, but please, try to be more friendly. The unmanaged world is completely alien to people who only ever worked with managed memory. There's no point in driving people off for having a reasonable question, even if the answer is completely obvious to you.

Comment: In the unmanaged world, the problems don't end just because the types match. Especially when you're doing casts. The cast in `(unsigned char*)type.c_str();` should have tipped you off that you're doing something very wrong; there's a _reason_ why `c_str()` returns a `const char*`. Do you have someone who can actually write C++ code you could ask for help? C++ is very different from C#, even though it may seem superficially similar. Trying things at random and hoping you get something that works is a horrible thing to do in the unmanged world - there's very few safety nets.

Comment: Worse, things can _appear_ to work correctly, while you're doing something very wrong. When things go bad, these issues are almost impossible to debug, because you're relying on things that aren't reliable - like "is this pointer still going to be valid outside of the function call?". You're lucky you got gibberish as a result - if you didn't, you'd be in far bigger trouble down the road :)

Comment: Okay thank you @Luaan.  I will have a talk with the person who is experienced in C++ but he has been out of the game for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ code is wrong.

```
imInfo.barcodeType = (unsigned char*)type.c_str();
imInfo.barcodeData = (unsigned char*)data.c_str();
```

`c_str()` gives you a pointer to the start of a string of characters, yes. You can pass that to a function, fine. But you *can't return it*! Who owns the memory? What is its lifetime? When is it deallocated? C++ doesn't have automatic memory management - you can't just return objects and pointers and expect them to magically work. You can't even rely on this bad behaviour to produce errors, as you've just seen - you get garbage; sometimes you get the right thing, sometimes the wrong thing, sometimes you introduce a horrible security flaw.

By the point `ScanBarcode` returns, `type` and `data` are destroyed. The pointer returned by `c_str()` isn't pointing to the data you think it's pointing to (regardless of the internal implementation of `c_str()`). You need to copy that data over to shared memory, and make sure it's freed properly. Passing memory around is *not* an easy thing in the unmanaged world. That's one of the big reasons why managed systems and languages like C# were designed in the first place.

Designing the interop is not trivial. Take examples from actual well-designed C APIs. One important thing is to return the length of the string, for example (it's very rare that you want to pass *just* `char*`, without also specifying the length; it's outright crazy to do that if you don't own the  memory being pointed to). First, decide who is supposed to allocate and deallocate the memory (this should usually be the same).

You can already see this is a bit of a problem. `ImageInfo` is allocated by the caller. But the `char*`fields are allocated by the callee! There is no way to sensibly limit the lifetime of the object to either the C++ or C# side (again, it's not the C# that's the problem - a C++ caller would have the same issue). The usual way this was handled in the olden days was with pre-allocated buffers - that is, `imInfo.barcodeType` would not be a pointer to a string, but an array. The C# structure would then look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct ImageInfo
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=255 /* this must be synchronized with the C++ code! */)]
  public string barcodeType;
}
```

The C++ side would do something like this (*do not use this in production code*, it's almost certainly wrong in some way - my C++ is very rusty; consult with a C++ programmer):

```
struct ImageInfo
{
  char barcodeType[255];
}

if (type.barcodeType.length() < 254) 
{
  strcpy(imInfo.barcodeType, type.c_str());
}
```

Again, this is extremely naive and probably wrong. It's just to show one way you can approach passing data between the caller and callee in general. Take good care.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I have removed `c_str()` from C++ and replaced it with a `std::copy`: `std::copy(symbol->get_type_name().begin(), symbol->get_type_name().end(), imInfo.barcodeType);`. Sadly this returnes the same gibberish.

Comment: @wes You're still randomly trying APIs and hoping it goes right. The unmanaged world doesn't work that way. Memory management is complicated. See my edit for an outline of an approach that would work (but is probably still very wrong). The C# side is the easy part; you need an actual C++ programmer for the C++ side. What you're doing is wrong in C++, and calling the method in C++ would give you the same gibberish. Interop isn't to blame in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I have had C++ for about a year in uni, but no where near this. I think I'm way out of my depth trying to get this to work.

Comment: @wes I've done C++ for something like 3 years, and done some game and embedded development etc., a long time ago. I still wouldn't dare writing the C++ side of the problem; I'm well aware of the pitfalls and minefields, but I'm not good enough to design and implement something that's _foolproof_. If I had to, I would start with getting reacquainted with the memory model, all the possible failure modes etc. before I even tried to write the code. Which is still going to be like 3 lines of code, mind you - but those lines are far tricker to get right than in C# :)

Answer (score -1):

A [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) is **not** a string.

Changing your struct to:

```
public struct ImageInfo
{
    public IntPtr data; // image data, works
    public int size;    // image data, works

    // string
    //public IntPtr barcodeType; // return gibberish
    //public IntPtr barcodeData; // return gibberish

    public string barcodeType;
    public string barcodeData;
}
```

should work, because the compiler now has a known value (sort of) type it can pass to your C++ struct.
A StringBuilder won't work, because this is an object which can't be converted to a string, instead the compiler would have to know to call the .ToString() method.

Comment: Without changing anything else the program will just crash on runtime without, only giving an exit code: -1073740940 (0xc0000374). I like the idea, but what I have read on the internet is that a C++ string cannot be send to a C# string directly, I can be wrong on this though.

Comment: @wes C++ string (`std::string`) cannot; C string certainly can. You really need to add more information about the C++ struct - the typedef of the struct doesn't tell us anything about what's actually in the `char*` fields. We don't even know if it's _supposed_ to be a string (`char*` is also used for byte arrays), and if so, what is the format, encoding etc. You can't just randomly try marshalling methods until you find one that seems to work. If this is part of the public API (and you don't have the sources), all of this should be documented.

Comment: @Luaan in both char* there can be numbers and letters. Example: '39123439' and 'code 128'.  I'm not sure what you mean with format and encoding. What I have added to the post is all the code in question. I left out some code that is not important to this question and what is working.

Comment: One thing to remember, is that C# strings are Unicode (UTF-16), C++ and C strings and ASCII, but you can easily put UTF-8 in there. So another possibility, would be to put byte[]s in your C# struct and set their values with C# encoding classes, by converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8